# Linq Query to sum only values above specific threshold

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I am having a hard time isolating values above a certain threshold from a column. I need to calculate only the miles that exceed 100 and multiply that with a rate. For example, if I have 101 miles on one row, 102 miles on the next one and 103 on another day, my desired sum would be `1*myrate + 2*myrate + 3*myrate`

```
private void SetMiles()
    {
    int.TryParse(MDate.ToString("MM"), out int month);
    int.TryParse(MDate.ToString("yyyy"), out int year);

    TotalMiles = Decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(MyTable
        .Where(a => a.Date <= MDate & a.Date.Month == MDate.Month & (a.Date.Year) == year & a.Miles > 100)
        .Select(a => a.Miles).Sum() * myrate), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); 
    }
```

The above does not work properly but that is my starting point. How can I accomplish my goal and keep it as simple as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `Select` to take the difference:

```
TotalMiles = Decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(MyTable
    .Where(a => a.Date <= MDate && a.Date.Month == MDate.Month && (a.Date.Year) == year && a.Miles > 100)
    .Select(a => a.Miles - 100).Sum() * myrate), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Also note that you need `&&` as the logical AND operator

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you @mmathis.

Comment: `&` is also a logical AND operator.

Answer (score 1):

you could make property inside your class

```
public int Value {
        get {
            if (Miles > 100)
            {
                return (Miles - 100);
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }

        }
    }
```

then use this

```
select(a=>a.Value).Sum()*rate;
```

since those which doesn't exceed 100 will return 0 so they don't effect your result
the final code will be

```
TotalMiles = Decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(MyTable
.Where(a => a.Date <= MDate && a.Date.Month == MDate.Month && (a.Date.Year) == year)
.select(a=>a.Value).Sum() * myrate), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```